# How can I have separate Bootstrap modal for every single row?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table containing multiple rows from a database, and I wanna have an icon to give delete option for every single record. I used [this tutorial](https://www.codexworld.com/bootstrap-modal-dynamic-content-jquery-ajax-php-mysql/) to create dynamic content modals, but now my issue is how can I have separate modals for different rows?

One way (which seems not feasible) is creating the modals dynamically using PHP (for each row, produce separate modal), but I believe there should be some way to have only one single modal, to be opened by passing an id or sth like this, and based on that id a customized content to be shown and later, delete the row.

Can somebody help me to change the code in the tutorial to reflect the need?

This is my code:
PHP

```
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success openBtn" id="1">Open Modal</button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success openBtn" id="2">Open Modal 2</button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Bootstrap Modal with Dynamic Content</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <form method="POST" action="delete.php" class="form-horizontal">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">cancel</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">confirm</button>
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="resource" value="<?=$section?>">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
$('.openBtn').on('click',function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$('.modal-body').load('getContent.php?id='+id,function(){
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
});
```

Comment: It's certainly possible to do it dynamically. Though it would help if you update your question to show what you have already tried in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That's what the tutorial does in the "Load Dynamic Content from Database in Bootstrap Modal" section. How's that different from what you are trying to do?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I added my code snippet to give a better idea. Note two hidden values for the section and record id, which should be populated based on the record ID and respective section. How can I pass these two values to the modal dynamically?

Comment: Store the value in javascript object, then assign them after open the modal

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Enclose delete `button` in to `table` `td`.
As PHP loop run it add the delete button to every single row.

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <td>Delete</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!--php code-->
    <!--start php loop-->

    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <!--Modal Trigger Buton-->
        <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--BootstrapModal Goes Here-->
```